# Another more efficient way for a big function

Tags: php, laravel

I was wondering if a function like this big would be ok. If not, is there any other efficient methods to make it easier, faster and perform efficiently without being slow? Should I also separate some of the actions into different functions?
If so I would also have to repeat the $output because of id?

```
public function select(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {

            if (Auth::user()) {

                $output="";
                $id = auth()->user()->id;

                if ($request->action) {

                    if ($request->action === "destroy_sales") {

                        Sales::where('id',$request->item_id)->where('spreadsheet_id', $request->spreadsheet_id)->delete();

                    }else if ($request->action === "edit_sales") {

                        $post = new Sales;
                        $post = Sales::find($request->item_id);
                        $post->spreadsheet_id = $request->spreadsheet_id;
                        $post->sold_price = $request->name;
                        $post->sold_price = $request->sold_price;
                        $post->save();

                    }



                    if (Auth::user()->subscribed('main')) {
                        $sales = DB::table('Sales')->where('user_id', '=', $id)
                        ->where('spreadsheet_id', '=', $request->spreadsheet_id)
                        ->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date])->get();

                        $summary = DB::table('Sales')->where('user_id', '=', $id)
                        ->where('spreadsheet_id', '=', $request->spreadsheet_id)
                        ->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date]);

                        if ($request->action == "summary") {

                            $sales = DB::table('Sales')->where('user_id', '=', $id)
                            ->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date])->get();

                            $summary = DB::table('Sales')->where('user_id', '=', $id)
                            ->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date]);

                        }
                    }else{
                        $sales = DB::table('Sales')->take(3)->where('user_id', '=', $id)
                        ->where('spreadsheet_id', '=', $request->spreadsheet_id)
                        ->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date])->get();

                        $summary = DB::table('Sales')->take(3)->where('user_id', '=', $id)
                        ->where('spreadsheet_id', '=', $request->spreadsheet_id)
                        ->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date]);

                        if ($request->action == "summary") {

                            $sales = DB::table('Sales')->take(3)->where('user_id', '=', $id)
                            ->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date])->get();

                            $summary = DB::table('Sales')->take(3)->where('user_id', '=', $id)
                            ->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date]);

                        }
                    }


                    if ($sales->count()>0) {

                        $output.="
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Sold Price</th>
                                    <th>Item Cost</th>
                                    <th>Shipping Charge</th>

                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            ";
                            foreach ($sales as $key => $sales) {
                                 $output.=
                                 '<tr>'.
                                    '<th><input type="text" name="name" value="'.$sales->name.'"></th>'.
                                    '<th><input type="number" name="sold_price" value="'.$sales->sold_price.'"></th>'.
                                    '<th><input type="number" name="item_cost" value="'.$sales->item_cost.'"></th>'.
                                    '<th><button class="sales_edit" id="'.$sales->id.'">Edit</button><button class="sales_delete" id="'.$sales->id.'">Delete</button>
                                        <input id="'.$sales->id.'sheet" type="hidden" value="'.$sales->spreadsheet_id.'"></input>
                                    </th>'.
                                '</tr>';
                            }
                        $output.=
                        "</table>";

                        return response()->json([
                            'spreadsheet_grid'   =>$output,
                            'spreadsheet_sales'=>array(
                                "sold_price"     => $summary->sum('sold_price')+$summary->sum('shipping_charge'),
                                "item_cost"      => $summary->sum('item_cost')+$summary->sum('shipping_cost'),
                                "fees"           =>$summary->sum('fees')+$summary->sum('other_fees')+$summary->sum('processing_fees'),
                                "profit"         =>$summary->sum('profit'),
                                "item_id"        =>$sales->spreadsheet_id
                            )
                        ]);

                    }else{
                        $output.="<div>Empty</div>";
                        return response()->json([
                            'spreadsheet_grid'   =>$output,
                            'spreadsheet_sales'=>array(
                            "sold_price"         =>0,
                            "item_cost"          =>0,
                            "fees"               =>0,
                            "profit"             =>0
                            )
                        ]);
                    }

                }       

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: as a start if only authenticated users can do these actions why not use auth middleware ?

Comment: and if you querying on condition you can do something like this $sales = DB::table('Sales')->where('user_id,$id);  if($request->action = 'ok'){$sales->where('sheet',$request->sheet');} and at the end you do $sales->get();

Comment: Every `$request->action` should be their own controller method and be routed individually.

Comment: not to mention most of that slow response is coming from creating html with php

Comment: @Namoshek oh i did not even see that :D nice one

Comment: @AhmedAboud You think I should just do a foreach loop in my view instead? What should I do about it?

Comment: Belongs to Site: Code Review...

Comment: if you are intend to use json why send a html ? loop through js yes

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using laravel, you are writing dirty php code inside laravel framework.

- if you want to this method only works for authenticated users add this route to `auth` middleware.
- if you want to this function to only works with ajax, you have two options:

  1. add a middleware that only allows ajax request and throws 404 on others.
  2. use this code:

```
if(!$request->ajax()) abort(404);

// and rest of your method
```

- use some validation in your code:

```
$request->validate([
            "action" => [
                "required",
                Rule::in(["destroy_sales", "edit_sales"])
            ],
            "item_id" => [
                "required",
                function($attribute, $value, $fail){
                    try {
                        Sales::findOrFail($value);
                    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $exception){
                        $fail($exception->getMessage());
                    }
                }
            ]
        ]);
```

- make two new protected methods for delete and editing your sale model or make two new route, like `Route::resource("sales", "SaleController");`
- update your model using mass update feature of laravel. add a protected property named `fillable` to your sale model with properties it have like: ("spreadsheet_id", "name", "sold_price") and use:

```
Sale::find($request->item_id)->update($request->all());
```

- use relations instead of attaching `spreadshit_id` manually

at this point you can reduce your method size something like 70%.

Comment: If I add two more protected methods would I have to copy and paste the output of it? Because after editing and deleting my spreadsheet refreshes.

Comment: you mean copy and paste spreadsheat spreadsheets? if yes, you can make a protected property named `spreadSheetContent` and put the content inside it and access it during runtime by `$this->spreadSheetContent`.